# How to get AngularStrap delay working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to do the delay for popover & dropdown for AngularStrap based on the documentation http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/popovers#tooltips

When the delay is a number it works.

```
<button type="button" data-trigger="click" data-placement="right" title="{{title}}" data-content="{{content}}" html="true" data-delay="1000" bs-popover>Click to toggle popover</button>
```

But when the delay is the object it doesn't works:

```
<button type="button" data-trigger="click" data-placement="right" title="{{title}}" data-content="{{content}}" html="true" data-delay="{ show: 500, hide: 100 }" bs-popover>Click to toggle popover</button>
```

How can I get it works?

Comment: You are probably using the older version of angular strap and referring to new version's document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a look into the mgcrea code for you and the way they've coded leads to accepting values in the format of "show, hide"

It's not coherent with their documents but the way you can get it to work is by having

```
<button type="button" data-trigger="click" data-placement="right" title="{{title}}" data-content="{{content}}" html="true" data-delay="500,100" bs-popover>Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Comment: Wow, yeah, that's not even close to the docs, but this works.  Thanks!